# How do I roll back Win10 Creators Update from command line?

Tags: windows-update

My Surface Pro 4 is stuck at a black screen after installing Creators Update.

I can get task manager to open, but it can't launch explorer (it shows a small blank window that says "personalized settings" for half a second then it disappears).

I got command prompt up.

"Start ms-settings:" fails ("the wait operation timed out") so I can't access the settings window to do the rollback.

Explorer works in safe mode but I can't open settings in there either.

I googled for a way to uninstall from command prompt and found wusa /uninstall /kb #### but I don't know what the update number is for Creators Update. I found a command that lists installed updates but it only showed a single security update.

I do see a Windows.old folder in my c drive now, so I'd like to roll back the upgrade.

Any suggestions?

As I was writing up this post i got two blue screens for PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA. Don't care to figure this out. I just want to roll back and get back to more important things.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you run `sfc /scannow` That seems the best thing to get this fixed, because until you can actually do something, I don't see a way to roll back the update.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by locking the computer and using the power button icon in the bottom right to restart while holding shift key.  From there, I found an option to revert to a previous version of windows.  It was kinda hidden behind a link to "click for more options" or something like that, which I didn't notice at first beneath all the buttons for other options.

The roll back was quick and I'm up and running now.  Thanks!